# Hazelcast ILock not working in cluster while updating map inside the lock scope

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a clustered environment having 2 nodes (i.e. 2 JVMs). And I am trying to check a Hazelcast IMap inside a Hazelcast ILock for key presence, as shown below:
**SOLUTION 1:**

```
public static final String CUR_ACC_MAP = "CUR_ACC_MAP";
private static final HazelcastInstance hazelInstance = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("accountCache");

public static boolean currencyAccountCreationInPorgress(String key) {
    ILock lock = hazelInstance.getLock(CUR_ACC_MAP);
    lock.lock();
    try {
        IMap<Object, Object> map = hazelInstance.getMap(CUR_ACC_MAP);
        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.putIfAbsent(key, System.currentTimeMillis());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

But the problem is, when simultaneous requests are invoked in 2 nodes, then both the nodes enters inside the if condition [if (!map.containsKey(key)) { ... }].
Due to this, both the nodes in the cluster returns false from the above mentioned method. Is there anything I am doing worng?

I have initially tried following code, which was also not working, so I switched to SOLUTION 1 above, but that is also not working.

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
public static final String CUR_ACC_MAP = "CUR_ACC_MAP";
private static final HazelcastInstance hazelInstance = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("accountCache");

public static boolean currencyAccountCreationInPorgress(String key) {
    IMap<Object, Object> map = hazelInstance.getMap(CUR_ACC_MAP);
    map.lock(CUR_ACC_MAP);
    try {
        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.putIfAbsent(key, System.currentTimeMillis());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        map.unlock(CUR_ACC_MAP);
    }
}
```

Here is my Hazelcast config:

```
    <hz:hazelcast id="hzInstance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:instance-name>accountCache</hz:instance-name>
        <hz:group name="hzAcc" password="Vam123" />
        <hz:network port="${account.hazelcast.port}" port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="${account.hazelcast.join.tcpip.enabled}">
                    <hz:members>${account.hazelcast.members}</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>

        <!-- Account File Upload Concurrent Processing Maps -->
        <hz:map name="CUR_ACC_MAP" max-idle-seconds="60" eviction-policy="LRU" max-size="100000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rajib,

- In Solution 2, try using `map.lock(key)` instead, it should work, even if there is no key to lock.
- In Solution 1, if both of your members are part of the same Hazelcast cluster, then only one of them should access the `if` block , not both.
- Better solution, without a lock, is this:

```
public static boolean currencyAccountCreationInPorgress(String key) {
    return hazelInstance.getMap(CUR_ACC_MAP).putIfAbsent(key, System.currentTimeMillis()) != null;
}
```

`putIfAbsent` operation is atomic, so can only be completed successfully once, all other requests will just return the previous value so your method will just return  true.

Comment: I have tried map.lock(key) also, that did not work. Then I switched to: map.lock(CUR_ACC_MAP). Not sure, what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that both app nodes are part of the same cluster?

Comment: Yes, both the nodes are part of the same cluster.

Comment: Can you share your Hazelcast config & some logs showing the cluster members from each node, if possible?

Comment: Here is the hazelcast config in xml:

Comment: <hz:hazelcast id="hzInstance">
  <hz:config>
   <hz:instance-name>accountCache</hz:instance-name>
   <hz:group name="hzAcc" password="Vam123" />
   <hz:network port="${account.hazelcast.port}" port-auto-increment="true">
    <hz:join>
     <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
     <hz:tcp-ip enabled="${account.hazelcast.join.tcpip.enabled}">
      <hz:members>${account.hazelcast.members}</hz:members>
     </hz:tcp-ip>
    </hz:join>
   </hz:network>

   <hz:map name="CUR_ACC_MAP" max-idle-seconds="60" eviction-policy="LRU" max-size="100000" />

Comment: can you also check & share some logs showing membership info. If you can share after both nodes started, you should see something like this in the logs: ```Members {size:2, ver:2} [
        Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 50a65065-e525-4f67-97dd-670f99d4830d
        Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - 192d3e3d-76fa-4a7c-9342-1ec7f9358b05 this
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this if you need to lock the hazalcast instance.Look like you are trying to lock on the instance name. Please use the instance object.It will work

```
Config cfg = new Config();
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
Lock lock = hz.getLock(object_to_lock);
lock.lock();
try {
        IMap<Object, Object> map = hazelInstance.getMap(CUR_ACC_MAP);
        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.putIfAbsent(key, System.currentTimeMillis());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
```